# A hierarchical config repository. Is this a thing?

Tags: configuration-management

It's always a challenge in this business finding the right level of abstraction.

We are regularly confronted with the need for, let's say, variables in our web apps, whose values are created at "config" time by admin users, then resolved at runtime, with hierarchical axes where you pick up the value that's most specific. So the classic example would be a user axis, where a team value, if specified, will override an organisation value. There's absolutely nothing specific to our business in this, but is there an app already out there? I've worked with config management systems like Hashi Consul that come close. Are there other things out there?

Values would need to have start dates and end dates. Axes would need to be customisable (i.e. I decide what my axes are, they don't belong to the tool.) There would be an admin interface for creating items and values, and an (HTTP?) API for querying. There would need to be some notion of grouping to let us retrieve, and perhaps edit, a group of items at once.

Is this a thing?